# How does a time delay contact remain open

Tags: relay, delay

If input voltage energizes a repeat cycle time delay relay coil, and the contact closes thus energizing output to the load for t1, how is the contact is able to open after t1, if it's still energized to a closing position by the coil? I,m a learner, but it seems the coil is energized throughout the cycle and the contact is both closing and, after the specified delay, opening, despite coil energization.

Comment: Can you give us a part number, a link or better still, embed the relevant information in the question? Welcome to SE.

Comment: I want to understand how an energized relay contact can, after its specified delay period, open or close against what seems to me a still energized/energizing coil.

Comment: On its own it can't. With some electronics inside it can. See the answers. I asked for the part number because something seems to have triggered this question and you would get a specific answer if you ask a specific question.

Comment: often these relays have another connection to power the timer and the relay coil during the delay.

Comment: @transistorYes, I am trying to understand the internal circuit of trs51a13s2a Time Delay Module shown on Infitec site.  it controls the fixed on time and adjustable off time of my pellet stove motor.  I'm trying to visualize the current flow among the numbered connectors.  according to the wiring diagram Line enters #1, motor neutral enters at #2, Line Neutral is #3.  A pot is connected from#6 and 7. I figure #4 to #10 is the fixed delay. Any insight greatly appreciated by this beginner.

Answer (score 1):

They're not just a relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGs5Ga.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Pulse relay.*

This relay will turn on with Vin but switch off automatically when the time delay is complete.

- On power up (Vin goes +) Vc1 will be 0 V. The output of the Schmitt trigger will be high, Q1 will turn on and the relay will be energised.
- After a time delay (approximately R x C seconds) C1 will have charged up enough to trigger the Schmitt trigger and its output switch low. Q1 will turn off and the relay drop out.
- D1 protects the transistor from inductive kick when switching off.
- The circuit is simplified and doesn't have a quick discharge for C1 when the power is switched off.
- The timing diagram on the right shows the relationship between input and output.
- Making R2 variable allows user adjustment of the time.

There are many configurations of these timer relays with delay-on, delay-off, one-shot, pulse-train, etc.

---

> The symbol inside the timer--two parallel lines--sometimes means
>   capacitor and sometimes means relay contact, I guess. What is it
>   representing here?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7liZh.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A capacitor and draftsman's contact.*

The symbols look similar but the lines on a capacitor are close together giving a simple representation of the two plates of a capacitor separated by a small gap. The draftsman's contact is just an easier way to draw a contact than the switch shown in the relay in Figure 1. (Ignore the dots in the symbol. The schematic editor puts them in when wires touch.)

> I'm not advanced enough to know what a triac is, but how could you
>   tell there was one present here? Continued thanks to you for your
>   instructive answers!!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhSm5B.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Symbol for a triac.*

[image: Dual timer]

*Figure 4. The [TRS51A13S2A](http://www.infitec.com/series/pdf/196b25cd31933286928c481e5ff3f762.pdf) dual timer module.*

There are a couple of clues that it's not a relay (with coil and moving contacts).

1. The physical size makes it unlikely.
2. There's no need. Relays are expensive relative to solid-state devices.
3. The datasheet says, "Fully Solid State And Encapsulated". This one settles the issue.

   - A triac is a semiconductor device with two power terminals (top and bottom of the symbol) and a gate (sticking out the side of the symbol).
   - It acts like a normally off switch but if a voltage pulse is given to the gate the triac turns on and remains on until the current somehow falls to zero.
   - With AC supply the current is reversing 50 or 60 times a second, depending where you live. Since it's reversing it crosses through zero 100 or 120 times a second. All we have to do is trigger when we want current to flow and turn off the trigger when we want it to stop. The triac will turn off on the next zero-cross.
   - Triacs have no moving parts and are cheap.

Comment: I am beginning to think that this delay timer of mine is far more intricate than I originally visualized.

Comment: Yes the [TRS51A13S2A](http://www.infitec.com/series/pdf/196b25cd31933286928c481e5ff3f762.pdf) module has two build-in timers. The switching is done by a triac so there isn't even a relay in it. The timing diagram is shown on the data sheet.

Comment: TRS51A13S2. The symbol inside the timer--two parallel lines--sometimes means capacitor and sometimes means relay contact, I guess.  What is it representing here? I'm not advanced enough to know what a triac is, but how could you tell there was one present here? Continued thanks to you for your instructive answers!!

Comment: Answer updated to address your latest comments.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the whole thing is you aren't directly energising the coil in a time-delay or other such fancy relay.

The wire you 'energise' drives both the coil and an internal timing circuit. It could be as simple as this for a delayed release relay:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjzWUi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this, at first the capacitor is discharged, because the input voltage was 0V and the R2 takes care of discharging. You connect, for example, 12V and the P-MOSFET sees a voltage of 0V on its gate compared to 12V on its source, so it turns on. Then also C1 starts charging through R1, at some point the MOSFET will start pinching off and the relay will turn off.

A diode is there to catch any switch-off spikes caused by the relay and is generally a good idea in any relay design where you know the polarity for 100% sure.

---

But that's just a simple little thing, the circuit can involve one or more chips, even microcontrollers to set certain intervals and all such things.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.  Some of this I understand, but as I'm just learning, some of it is over my head.

Comment: @Scott the central point of my answer is: There's more in there. The extra example is just for completeness.